Next JS Build Error with Custom Node Express server
need some help on a longstanding problem that I still have no idea how to fix. Been reading through Stack posts, Github issues, and on this subreddit but I stick can't find a reason.
Sample code (other pages affected have this type of structure):
/public/profiles.json
[{...}, {...}]

/pages/search.js
import SearchTool from '@/components/Search'
import { fetchGetProfiles } from '@/lib/api'
export default function Search({ profiles }) {
    return (
        <>
            <SearchPage profiles={ profiles } />
        </>
    )
}
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const profiles = await fetchGetProfiles()
    return { props: { profiles } }
}

/lib/api.js
import { serverData } from '@/lib/config'

export async function fetchGetProfiles() {
    const res = await fetch(`${serverData}/public/profiles.json`, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    return res
}

/lib/config.js
export const serverData = 'http://localhost:8082/testingApp'

/server.js
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
 
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = parseInt(process.env['APP_ROOT'] || '8082');
const appName = process.env['APP_NAME'] || 'testingApp'
const dataDir = process.env['APP_DATA'] || path.resolve(__dirname, "./public")
const profilesPath = path.resolve(dataDir, "./profiles.json")

const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
 
app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();
  server.use(bodyParser.json());
  server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  server.get(`/${appName}/public/profiles.json`, (req, res) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(profilesPath, 'utf-8'))
    res.status(200).send(data);
  })

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}/${appName}/`)
  })
})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})

PROBLEM
Running npm run build for the project results in the following:

Error: Error serializing \.profiles` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/search".`
Reason: \undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.`
at ...(error stack)....
TypeError: fetch failed
at ...(error stack)...

On development mode, this works completely okay so I'm not really sure what the problem is during build. Also heard that getStaticProps should be capable of fetching on SSR so I don't think this should be the problem.
Could anyone help me on this part please? Much appreciated!
I've tried altering the fetch URL and making sure data read read in properly by fs to send through response.  Supposedly should expect the build to proceed as normal with data extracted from the file and populated when browser starts after the build.
